# $\{\implies, \vee\}$ and $\{\iff,\lnot\}$ cannot express all the truth functions

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples, propositional-calculus

Counterexample to see that $\{\implies, \vee\}$ and $\{\iff,\lnot\}$ are not alone adequate to express all the truth functions.

what could be the counterexample?

what expression could not be expressed with these pairs of operators?

I don't know how to do it.

Comment: The last one is a bit tricky, but the first pair should be clear... both functions preserve truth, i.e. if $Q, R$ are true, so is their disjunction and any conditional formed with them. Which connective *does not* have this property?

Comment: @Nagase you're right $\lnot$?

Comment: By "v" do you mean "or"? That is `\vee` and `\wedge` for "and" in LaTeX.

Comment: @MichelleGarcía - Yes, that's it.

Comment: @Dair Perhaps easier to remember: \lor and \land (along with \implies, \lnot, \iff)

Comment: Every function in the first span will have the property $F(\top,~ \top,~ \top, \dots) = \top$.  Every function in the second span will have the property $F(x,~ y_1,~ y_2,~ y_3,~ \dots) = \lnot F(\lnot x,~ y_1,~ y_2,~y_3,~ \dots)$.

Comment: @DanielV I don't get your comment, how do I relate it to my question?

Comment: You don't understand what I said, or you do understand what I said but not how it is relevant?

Comment: @DanielV I don't understand what you said

Comment: There is a set of functions that can be defined by composing $\{\to, \lor \}$, call that set $S$.  For example, $F(a, b, c) = a \lor (b \to c)$ is one of them.  Every function in $S$ has the property that if all the inputs are true, then the output is true.

Comment: @DanielV I see but how do you know that? in which book did you find that result? and again I still cannot see the relation with my question

Answer (score 4):

As was pointed out in a comment to the original post, both $\implies$ and $\lor$ are *truth-preserving*, which means (check this!) that all compositions of $\implies$ and $\lor$ will be truth-preserving. Since for example $\lnot$ isn't truth-preserving, $\{\implies,\lor\}$ cannot be functionally complete.

You can do something very similar for the other set. The connectives $\iff$ and $\lnot$ both happen to be *affine* (or *linear*), and it can be shown (but this is tricky) that all compositions of affine connectives are affine themselves. Since not all truth functions are affine (find a counterexample yourself!), $\{\iff,\lnot\}$ cannot be functionally complete.

A good place to start reading more about this is the section about [characterization of functional completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness#Characterization_of_functional_completeness) on Wikipedia. Another excellent reference, that focuses specifically on $\{\iff,\lnot\}$, is the article [On Proving Functional Incompleteness
in Symbolic Logic Classes](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ndjfl/1093637874) from 1988 by Pelletier and Sharp.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2512018/21820), there is an elementary method to show that the entire set $\{¬,⊕,⇔,⊤,⊥\}$ is not adequate.