# Defining The $\%$ Connective

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Everybody,
Consider the $\%$ truth function. It has the same truth table for $\%$ is the same as a negated biconditional.

I need to determine whether all truth functions can be symbolized using only the $\%$ connective. But I already know that the set of connectives $\{\land, \lor, \neg\}$ is adequate insofar as all truth functions can be symbolized containing no connectives not in THAT set.

So, if the  $\{\%\}$ is adequate then I can define every connective in $\{\land, \lor, \neg\}$ in terms of only $\{\%\}$.

I don't think that this can be done. A conjunction is a two-place truth function s.t.
i (1, 1) = 1
i (1, 0) = 0
i (0, 1) = 0
i (0, 0) = 0

However,it doesn't seem like there's any formula consisting in just the $\%$ connective that can capture this, as the two place function is true on the fist row (i.e., when any sentence letters in the formula are true) but if two sentence letters in $\phi\mathbin{\%}\psi$ are true then $\phi\mathbin{\%}\psi$ is false.

Does any have tips about how to proceed, i.e., how to go about giving a proof of whether all truth-functions can be symbolized by $\%$?

Comment: Hmm do you get my answer? Feel free to ask if you need clarification. And I noticed you haven't accepted any answer to any of your questions (not just this one). Are they all unsatisfactory to you?

Answer (score 1):

Your $\%$  operator appears to be what is often called XOR,
with the truth table
\begin{array}{ccc}
x & y & x\% y \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}

It is true that $\phi\%\psi$ is different from
$\phi \land \psi$ when $\phi$ and $\psi$ both are true, 
but this is not conclusive.
After all, the operator sometimes called NAND,
defined by $x \mathop{\mathrm{NAND}} y := \lnot(x\land y),$
also has the property that $\phi\mathop{\mathrm{NAND}}\psi$ 
is different from
$\phi \land \psi$ when $\phi$ and $\psi$ both are true,
but all truth functions *can* be constructed from the
NAND operator alone.

An interesting fact about XOR is that any sentence built
from any combination of atoms and XOR connectives
(without any other symbols)
is true if and only if an odd number of the atoms are true,
counting a true atom that appears $n$ times in the sentence
as $n$ true atoms.
If you have the right definitions for what makes a sentence,
it should be possible to define this fact inductively.
It should then be possible to show that none of the three 
operators $\{\land, \lor, \lnot\}$ can be implemented by XOR.

Comment: So my Base Then, doing Structural Induction on WFFs would be something like: every sentence letter is s.t. it is true if an odd number of its atoms is true?

Answer (score 0):

First, I should note that the % you have here is known as the $XOR$ (for which we sometimes use the symbol $\oplus$)

HINT

Use induction to show that any expression built up from $P$'s, $Q$'s, and any number of $XOR$'s will have an even number of $1$'s when evaluated on a truth table.

ALTERNATIVE HINT

Use induction to show that any expression $\phi$ using any variables and any number of $XOR$'s cannot capture the truth-function that would return True if all variables in $\phi$ are set to False.

Basic Set-up for latter:

Base: $\phi$ is some atomic statement $P$.  Clearly this does not capture any truth-function that returns True if $P$ is False.

Step: Suppose $\phi=\phi_1 \ XOR \ \phi_2$, where by inductive hypothesis neither $\phi_1$ nor $\phi_2$ captures any truth-function that returns True when all variables in $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are set to False respectively. Then neither $\phi_1$ nor $\phi_2$ captures any truth-function that returns True when all variables in $\phi$ are set to False, for setting all variables in $\phi$ to False implies setting all variables in $\phi_1$ and in $\phi_2$ to False. This means that when all variables in $\phi$ are set to False, both $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ evaluate to False, and hence $\phi = \phi_1 \ XOR \ \phi_2 = False \ XOR \ False = False$ ... meaning that $\phi$ cannot capture any truth-function that returns True when all variables in $\phi$ are set to False.

OK, so that concludes the inductive proof.  Are we there yet?  Not quite! Because all we have proven is that certain truth-functions as defined over certain variables cannot be proven using an expression built up from $XOR$'s and those very variables, but that does not immediately imply that you couldn't capture that truth-function using an expression built up from $XOR$'s and *any* variables (i.e including variables that may not be involved with the desired truth-function).  To see why this is important, consider what would happen if we could somehow create some expression $\psi$ using some other variables, and suppose that this statement would be equivalent to a tautology  ... then $\psi \ XOR \ P$ would be equivalent to $\neg P$, and so we'd be able to express $\neg P$ after all; something we seemed to have ruled out, but now realize might be possible after all.

So, how do we rule out the potential effect of any other variables? Well ... I must say I'm a bit stuck there myself ... Hmmm ... maybe you should go with my original HINT?

Comment: May I ask where this hint even came from when thinking about how to answer my question? I think I see where this is going but I have no idea how you thought of this.

Comment: @Rusty Your % is better known as the XOR ... and I just know a thing or two about the XOR from experience :)

Comment: Thanks, Bram! But how can I deduce your hint given only what I know here?

Comment: @Rusty You mean how would you come up with this particular claim about this particular connective?  Good question ... like so many math theorems it can take a while to see something like that ... but it's typically a matter of observing some small cases, noticing some pattern, and then seeing if this pattern holds in general. So, maybe you should do exactly that:  generate a few fairly statements involving some $P$'s, $Q$'s, and %'s, and work out their truth tables ... that'll give you some more feeling for how this operator works.

Comment: So my Base Then, doing Structural Induction on WFFs would be something like: every sentence letter is s.t. it is true if an odd number of its atoms is true?

Comment: @Rusty That's if you use the claim that the claim is true iff and odd number of its instances of variables is true, as suggested by David K in his answer ... which works as well, and is actually a bit simpler than what I suggested.  My method (which looks at the number of $1$'s in the truth table) is a bit more difficult, but still works if you could also use $\neg$'s. Thus, the % (XOR) by itself is not expressively complete, and even if you had the $\neg$ as well, you still wouldn't have expressive completeness.

Comment: So, these are both properties of WFFs (i.e., each WFF is s.t. it has an even number of 1's or s.t. a WFF is true iff an odd number of it's atomics are false) that can be inductively defined and thus both apt to be used in a structural induction that would fail to show that the salient property holds of all WFFs?

Comment: @Rusty Yes, though for the former you do need to specify that you have at least two different variables in the formula ... so that you get at least $4$ rows in the truth-rable.

Comment: So what is the salient property, exactly? Is the property that I'm showing holds for all WFFs just "if a WFF contains only that connective and the sentence letter P the WFF is true iff P has an odd number of negated sentence letters?

Comment: @Rusty Yeah, that'll work just fine ... and is in fact the easiest! All you need to do is to show (by induction) that any such formula cannot capture $\neg P$

Comment: Do you have hints about how to proceed? 
I'm getting mixed up in my head, so let me re say some things. I have a property of WFFs. I need to show, via structural induction, that it doesn't hold for $\neg\phi$. 

Does this mean I can skip straight to showing how this part of the inductive step doesn't go through? Or do I need to show that every sentence letter has the relevant property but THEN show that , assuming that $\phi$ has the property that $\neg\phi$ doesn't have it?

Comment: @Rusty So I was thinking some more about this myself and realized that actually it isn't as easy to prove that you cannot capture $\neg P$ ... so, I just provided a better HINT to my answer just now.

Comment: Now I'm stuck again: I'm confused about using a structural inductive proof to show that each WFF has a property that doesn't ""capture" some truth-function.  Can you gesture towards how I set up the base/inductive case here?

Comment: Can we chat, Bram? I've been trying to do an inductive proof on your original hint for a while now and I'm stuck. After all, the base case is just a iff $\phi$ s.t. it has one sentence letter and no connective but XOR, which is to say that $\phi$ here is a sentence letter. But it's NOT the case that $\phi$ has an even number of 1's in it's truth table

Comment: @Rusty OK, let's chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67675/discussion-between-bram28-and-rusty).

Comment: @Rusty: As you noticed, the claim in the first hint holds only for two or more propositional variables. As shown in my answer, this is because either all or exactly half of the truth assignments yield value $false$. Clearly, this is even if there are at least 2 propositional variables. =)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very short and clean answer.
$
\def\xor{\oplus}
\def\eq{\Leftrightarrow}
$

First notice (as in the other answers) that $x\%y = x \xor y$, where "$\xor$" is the standard symbol for xor. Then notice that $x \xor y = ( x + y ) \bmod 2$ if you treat $true,false$ as $1,0$. Thus immediately you get (from basic properties of modulo arithmetic) that $\xor$ is associative and commutative. Hence given any boolean expression comprising only propositions joined by $\xor$, you can freely rearrange it such that all the instances of each proposition are together, without changing its value. Clearly pairs of the same proposition can now be eliminated. Finally observe that if you change the truth value of any proposition that is not completely eliminated (which means it had occurred an odd number of times originally), you will flip the output. So either the output is always $false$ or the output is $true$ for exactly half the possible truth assignments.

For example, $( a \xor b ) \xor ( ( a \xor ( b \xor c ) ) \xor a ) = ( a \xor a \xor a ) \xor ( b \xor b ) \xor c = a \xor c$, where we can drop the brackets because of associativity.

---

Further exercise: Use the same kind of analysis to show that $\{\neg,\xor,\eq,\top,\bot\}$ is also not adequate. Hint:

> $\neg x = (x+1) \bmod 2$ and $x \eq y = (x+y+1) \bmod 2$.

Comment: 'select to see'? what does that mean?

Comment: I don't see the relation with my exercise btw. I just have 2 elements in my set

Comment: @MichelleGarcía: Use your mouse to select the blank to see the text. But you should be **trying first**. Also, I never said my answer answers your question in chat, but you had posted other questions on the main site that would have been trivially answered by the exact technique in my answer here. The goal is to understand the underlying mathematics rather than to just solve your questions.